# Typescript - How to get instance property name at transpile time

Tags: typescript

Does anyone know if there is a way, in Typescript, to output the name of an instance property at transpile time?

For instance, say I have a class:

```
class SomeClass {
   public someFn() { }
}
```

How would I generate the following pseudo-code before any instances of `SomeClass` have been created?

```
string str = nameof(SomeClass.someFn)
```

Note, this is for purposes of re-factoring, so I don't want to cycle through the prototype in code; I'm just wondering if there is a transpile time way of doing this? In other words, is there a way of getting the Typescript transpiler to spit out the name of the instance property as a string?

Why? I want a way of being able to access a known property of an instance that is safe to re-factoring, and that - unlike `someInstance.someFn` - is not determined at transpile-time. So you could for instance have a `switch` statement that accessed different properties that didn't rely on magic strings and would be refactorable. e.g. Rather than writing the following in code:

```
switch(input){
     case "someFn":
          return someObj["someFn"]();
}
```

I can write the following:

```
switch(input){
    case nameof(SomeClass.someFn):
        return someObj[nameof(SomeClass.someFn]();
}
```

The idea is that a global rename of the `someFn` variable will be propagated inside the switch statement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean at compile time? What would you then do with that name in compile time? It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: By compile time, I mean transpile time. I'll edit it.

Comment: That switch is happening in runtime and not in compile/transpile time. Also, I'm not sure what's the big difference between writing `SomeClass.someFn` and writing '"someFn"`.

Comment: @StephenEllis in the potential consuming code, do you have an instance of SomeClass, or do you want/need to refer to the class name 'statically'?

Comment: in terms of language support, FWIW [nameof suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579) was resolved in favor of the more general [Type Property type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1295) but that's not available anytime soon AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do because this:

```
switch (input) {
    case nameof(SomeClass.someFn):
        return someObj[nameof(SomeClass.someFn]();
}
```

Can work only if `input === "someFn"`, and you are writing in your code `SomeClass.someFn` so you are being specific about `someFn`.
Since that's the case then what's wrong with:

```
switch (input) {
    case "someFn":
        return someObj["someFn"]();
}
```

If you want to just make sure that the string in `input` is an existing method in `SomeClass` then you can:

```
if (Object.keys(SomeClass.prototype).indexOf(input) >= 0 && typeof SomeClass.prototype[input] === "function") {
    return someObj[input]();
}
```

Comment: No. The point is I want to be able to re-factor `someFn` in a more robust manner. Using string literals means if I want to rename `someFn` in the future, I have to use dumb string replacement to change the variable name. I want to use smarter refactoring tools (e.g. VS Ctrl+R+R) to rename the variable in the future.

Comment: But it still doesn't make sense. You pass a string to begin with (the `input`), and that you'll need to search/replace when you refactor. Also, since you have this string why not just do: `return someObj[input]()`? You have no control over the compiler (unless you go to great length and hack it) so you can not replace parts of the code at compilation time.  But there might be runtime solutions for your problem, it's just that I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes. Clearly in the limiting case it's pointless because you can right someObj[input]. That's not the point. Imagine a more complicated case. Say, you had two switch cases which return the opposing values.

Comment: Ok, so what's this more complicated case? Where do you get this `input`? What are you trying to actually do? Not a simple example, really what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have classes `class SomeCommands { someCommand: function() { //does some work }}` Then across the app, I call `invokeCommand(str: string)` which calls `someCommand` on an instance of SomeCommands. Now some of these common commands crop up a lot, so I want to avoid re-factor hell. i.e rather than call `invokeCommand("someCommand")` I want to call  `invokeCommand(nameof(SomeCommand.someCommand))`, so I could refactor the fn name. But it doesn't appear to be possible in Typescript.

Comment: I see. Well, it's not possible to do. I thought that maybe you can use [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) but that won't help much either.  If it's really important to you then you can use the [Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) but that won't be an easy task

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of an instance method without any magic strings, and in a way that is re-factorable, you can use the following: `SomeClass.prototype.someFn.name`

Comment: That produces an empty string

Comment: yeah, unfortunately confirmed that you can't do that since the transpiled code doesn't compile a named function, but instead does SomeClass.prototype.someFn = function () { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a better method, but without referring to the method by a string, [this seems to work](https://plnkr.co/edit/H6XZNMglukIdDn75eFvi?p=preview) (logs "function name is someMethod")

```
class SomeClass {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('in someMethod');
  }
}

function getFunctionName(classRef, functionRef) {
  for (const memberName in classRef.prototype) {
    const memberValue = classRef.prototype[memberName];
    if (memberValue === functionRef) {
      return memberName;
    }
  }  
}

const name = getFunctionName(SomeClass, SomeClass.prototype.someMethod);
console.log(`function name is ${name}`);
```